# ¿Cómo puedo Extraer datos que se encuentran dentro de la sección de CDATA de un XML con VBA?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Este archivo XML tiene una sección CDATA con datos que necesito extraer para un reporte, los datos contenidos en esta sección están en formato XML pero no se pueden importar a Excel en celdas individuales, se convierten en una sola celda.

Hasta ahora he podido importar solo los primeros datos de XML y aún no convertir el CDATA a XML.

[image: Ejemplo del archivo XML]

[image: Extracción de la etiqueta CDATA como texto]

¿Como puedo Convertir,con VBA; la sección CDATA en XML para poder recorrer los nodos y, por ejemplo; extraer el valor de la etiqueta SubtotalSinImpuestos?

Agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

al parecer es una factura electrónica de Ecuador. Yo lo he hecho "parsheando" el archivo y buscando las etiquetas, algo asì para tu ejemplo con el tag `<totalimpuestos>`

```
Sub tagxml()

Dim File
    'Archivo que se trabajara (camiar la ruta por uno tuyo)
    File = "C:\FACT_018002000119183.xml" 'archivo a parshear

    Set LibroNuevo = Workbooks.Add 'abrimos nuevo libro para trabajarlo
        LibroNuevo.Activate
        LibroNuevo.Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1") = "total sin impuestos" ' escribimos nuevo tag buscado
        LibroNuevo.Activate


    'Formateamos de acuerdo al tag que solicitamos
        Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0.00"

    'Abrimos el archivo con el método open file para almacenar la info del xml
            Open File For Input As #1
            Do While Not EOF(1) = True
            'Almacenamos información que lee el archivo
            Line Input #1, PrimeraLineaXML
            SegundaLineaXML = SegundaLineaXML & PrimeraLineaXML
            Loop

            Close #1

    'Regresamos al libro creado
        LibroNuevo.Worksheets("Hoja1").Select

    'Buscamos la ùltima fila con informaciòn y saltamos una para escribir
        Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    'Extraemos la info del tag con funciones MID e INSTR <totalSinImpuestos>
        ActiveCell.Value = Mid(SegundaLineaXML, InStr(1, SegundaLineaXML, "<totalSinImpuestos>") + 19, InStr(1, SegundaLineaXML, "</totalSinImpuestos>") - InStr(1, SegundaLineaXML, "<totalSinImpuestos>") - 19)


End Sub
```

Espero te pueda guiar, saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias, veo que estas tratando el XML como texto plano. voy a intentarlo para extraer solo la información que necesito.